Why does calling Trait::f(&true as &dyn Trait) still use the Trait implementation for bool in Rust?
I'm trying to understand the difference between inherent methods on dyn Trait and trait implementations for a specific type in Rust. I set up a trait, implemented it for bool, and dyn Trait. Here’s the code:
trait Trait {
    fn f(&self);
}

impl Trait for bool {
    fn f(&self) {
        print!("2");
    }
}

impl<'a> dyn Trait + 'a {
    fn f(&self) {
        print!("1");
    }
}

fn main() {
    Trait::f(&true);
    Trait::f(&true as &dyn Trait);
    <_ as Trait>::f(&true);
    <_ as Trait>::f(&true as &dyn Trait);
    <bool as Trait>::f(&true);
    <dyn Trait as Trait>::f(&true as &dyn Trait);
}


Can someone explain why the output is 222222

Isn't this from the Rust Quiz? There are explanations there.

https://github.com/dtolnay/rust-quiz/blob/master/questions/010-shadowed-trait-object-method.md

I'm not sure why you'd expect the output to be anything else, TBH. All of the lines in main explicitly invoke the trait method.
